# Can you multi stage build a docker image with both aws/gsutil cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

I am wondering if there is a straightforward way in docker to build an image that has both the aws cli and gsutil cli installed on it for use. Unfortunately, an s3 name containing periods creates a `Host ... returned an invalid certificate` error https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/267 and I cannot change the s3 bucket name unfortunately, which means I cannot do the following

```
gsutil -m cp -r "s3://path.with.periods/path/files" "gs://bucket_path/path"
```

so instead Ill have to do something like

```
aws s3 cp --recursive --quiet "s3://path.with.periods/path/files" ./
gsutil -m cp -r "./" "gs://bucket_path/path"
```

but I was wondering if there was a straightforward dockerfile that could run these commands?